# Generate empty object based on reactively interface

Tags: typescript, types, interface

I have interface that is generated base on enum and it has readonly keys

```
enum HealthPlanStatus {
    InProgress = 'InProgress',
    Completed = 'Completed',
}

export type THealthPlanCardsByStatus = {
    [status in keyof typeof HealthPlanStatus]: {
        cards: string[];
    };
}
```

In my project I want to correctly declare an empty object that is generated by **HealthPlanStatus**.

```
const cards = ['1', '2', '3']
const cardsGroupedByStatus: any = {}
Object.values(HealthPlanStatus).forEach(status => {
    cardsGroupedByStatus[status] = cards.filter(card => card)
})
```

To avoid errors it has now **"any"**, but I want to see any of this variants:

1. const cardsGroupedByStatus: THealthPlanCardsByStatus = {}
2. const cardsGroupedByStatus = {} as THealthPlanCardsByStatus

In both cases I have different errors:

1. *const cardsGroupedByStatus: THealthPlanCardsByStatus
   Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'THealthPlanCardsByStatus': InProgress, Completed*
2. *Cannot assign to 'InProgress' / 'Completed' because it is a read-only*

If it's not possible, please, give me advise how to correctly make declaration for new generates object.
Thanks!

[Link to reproduce errors](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=29&pln=12&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBAEsCGAbALgCwAqPiAys%20yYAzlAN4BQUVUAkiOgE4D2A5g8ESQLxQDkdjVu068ANJWoBhJhAAOiYMmAATKD17S5CpcrHkAvuXLAAHrKYNkUZAE9ZwKABU4SNJmyT4DZUQBCNvAJiNTIJKgBtInxCEgBLECgAa2AbJgAzaztgdNgEFAwsXGjiAF0ALlDqKqgAYy8fCqiGeJZwkoBuMKh9TsNyGqYQKNr67ihw3gBGMV4AJjE%20AGZeEqMBoas67yIAcWYwe2V-QJiQ0n0oeBJnPLdCz23j4qJyAHkAIwArYBrkADoAG5IMAcAAULny7iKQSIAEo-mkLABReA1VCgqIwtQAPkq1C2Pj2TAOKieMMizxKIQJRARsRQwAYoIJOJG3lhBlhQA)

Comment: Not enough context for error #2 - can't reproduce

Comment: You don't need `keyof typeof` in `THealthPlanCardsByStatus`, you can just remove it

Comment: Try `cardsGroupedByStatus: Partial<THealthPlanCardsByStatus>`

Comment: @ФаридАхмедов here is link to reproduce: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAEsCGAbALgCwAqPiAys+yYAzlAN4BQUVUAkiOgE4D2A5g8ESQLxQDkdjVu068ANJWoBhJhAAOiYMmAATKD17S5CpcrHkAvuXLAAHrKYNkUZAE9ZwKABU4SNJmyT4DZUQBCNvAJiNTIJKgBtInxCEgBLECgAa2AbJgAzaztgdNgEFAwsXGjiAF0ALlDqKqgAYy8fCqiGeJZwkoBuMKh9TsNyGqYQKNr67ihw3gBGMV4AJjE+AGZeEqMBoas67yIAcWYwe2V-QJiQ0n0oeBJnPLdCz23j4qJyAHkAIwArYBrkADoAG5IMAcAAULny7iKQSIAEo-mkLABReA1VCgqIwtQAPkq1C2Pj2TAOKieMMizxKIQJRARsRQwAYoIJOJG3lhBlhQA

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments:

1. You don't need `keyof typeof`, remove it and leave just:

```
export type THealthPlanCardsByStatus = {
    [status in HealthPlanStatus]: {
        cards: string[];
    };
}
```

2. Then you can use

```
const cardsGroupedByStatus = {} as THealthPlanCardsByStatus
Object.values(HealthPlanStatus).forEach(status => {
    cardsGroupedByStatus[status] = { // you forgot initialize object here
        cards: cards.filter(card => card)
    }
})
```

or

```
const cardsGroupedByStatus: Partial<THealthPlanCardsByStatus> = {}
Object.values(HealthPlanStatus).forEach(status => {
    cardsGroupedByStatus[status] = {
        cards: cards.filter(card => card)
    }
})
```

Comment: Even if I delete keyof typeof, but I have the same error in this case. Below in question you can find link to reproduce. {} as THealthPlanCardsByStatus or Partial<THealthPlanCardsByStatus> = {} not helping

Comment: Aaaah! It works with any type only and next I can add as after empty object